# Can EF prevent generation of primary key

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm creating a model that uses a GUID for the primary key. I set the GUID myself, then use EF to save the model to the SQL Server DB. During the call to `DbContext.SaveChanges()`, the GUID is changed. Can I prevent this?

Edit:

The class is not decorated in anyway. Guid is set by static constructor:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public Guid MyEntityId { get; set; }

    public static MyEntity CreateMyEntity()
    {
        return new MyEntity { MyEntityId = Guid.NewGuid() };
    }
}
```

The DB constrains the ID field as `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED`

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have this:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public GUID GUIDField { get; set; }
```

`[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` line tells the EF to set GUID value himself. remove that attribute and you are done.

Comment: Nope. Class is completely undecorated.

Comment: This is the class that Entity Framework generates, not your ViewModel class

Comment: @ben explicitly tell EF to not to add Identity: `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up your Entity like this:

```
public class SomeEntity 
{
    public SomeEntity() 
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Effectively, yes. That's how it's set up.